# Setting sendmail to send mail for another server

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I have a server with CentOS+Plesk+Qmail, I want to set it to send mail trough another server (CentOS+Sendmail).

What do I need to set at the second server end in order to accept and deliver email for first server ?

The first server is forwarding the email trough Qmail smtproutes but the other server is saying:

does_not_like_recipient

What I want to send is from noreply@server1 to gmail, yahoo, etc.

Comment: What's with the down votes? Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to allow relaying from server1 on the second server. http://www.sendmail.org/tips/relaying

Comment: I got it to work but I wonder... if I replace the values of MX on server 1 to point to server 2, won't my server 1 know that it should send* email directly trough server 2 without having to edit things like smtproutes files in server 1?

Comment: That sounds like a new question... But generally I'd say: No, you don't want to add DNS issues into this mix. Kick back and watch it work. :-)